# Why does ngRepeat use a compile function, when all it does is return a linking function?

Tags: angularjs, directive

reading the [ngrepeat source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js), I was wondering why it defines a compile function, while all that does is return a linking function, it's not manipulating the template passed into the compile function, as far as I can see.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive read the section "Reasons behind the compile/link separation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at that source code link, it appears that the linking function does utilize a param from the compile function (the linker object).  As to why it needs the linker obj, I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the way the Directive Definition Object is defined:

You could also do:

```
compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
      }
```

Check Directives documentation at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

A **compile function** can have a return value which can be either a function or an object.

- returning a (post-link) function - is equivalent to registering the
  linking function via the link property of the config object when the
  compile function is empty.
- returning an object with function(s) registered via pre and post
  properties - allows you to control when a linking function should be
  called during the linking phase. See info about pre-linking and
  post-linking functions below.

Comment: Yes, I've read this documentation, but as far as I can tell, the ngRepeat code has a compile function that returns a function itself, which must be a postlink function, so why don't they simply define a "link" property on the document definition object?